# Is there a route to the end of the jump table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interview-questions, dynamic-programming

I'm currently learning about Dynamic Programming and solving a "coding question" related to the topic.

> Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned
> at the first index of the array.
>
> Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that
> position.
>
> Determine if you are able to reach the last index.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> Input: `[2,3,1,1,4]`
> Output: `true`
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> Input: `[3,2,1,0,4]`
> Output: `false`

Here's my code:

```py
    def canJump(nums: List[int]) -> bool:
        memo = {len(nums) - 1: True}
        def canJumpPos(pos):
            if pos >= len(nums):
                return False
            elif pos in memo:
                return memo[pos]
            else:
                for i in range(nums[pos], 0, -1):
                    if canJumpPos(i + pos):
                        return True
                memo[pos] = False
        
        return canJumpPos(0)
```

I'm having trouble reasoning about the time/space complexity of my approach. My understanding is that without memoization, this approach would be exponential. But, with memoization, this becomes a linear time algorithm? Is this correct? How would you recommend I calculate time complexity in the future when I'm dealing with dynamic programming?

Answer (score 4):

## All paths do not `return`

```
    def canJumpPos(pos):
        if pos >= len(nums):
            return False
        elif pos in memo:
            return memo[pos]
        else:
            for i in range(nums[pos], 0, -1):
                if canJumpPos(i + pos):
                    return True
            memo[pos] = False
            # Missing Return
```

This means `canJump([3,2,1,0,4])` returns `None`, not `False`!  A violation of your declared `-> bool` return.

## No memoization of `True`

When this code returns `True`:

```
                if canJumpPos(i + pos):
                    return True
```

`memo[pos]` is never set to `True`.  This means that if `canJumpPos(pos)` is called called with the same `pos` value, it will have to redo all the work it has already done to return the same `True` value!

## Eschew offset additions, assiduously

```
            for i in range(nums[pos], 0, -1):
                if canJumpPos(i + pos):
```

Here, you are always using `i + pos`, never `i` by itself.
Instead of repeating this addition over and over again,
you could roll that addition into the `range()` end-points.

```
            for i in range(nums[pos] + pos, pos, -1):
                if canJumpPos(i):
```

## Any and All

Looping over some condition until you find a `True` condition:

```
            for i in range(nums[pos] + pos, pos, -1):
                if canJumpPos(i):
                    return True
            # ...
```

is often better performed using `any(...)`:

```
            if any(canJumpPos(i) for i in range(nums[pos] + pos, pos, -1)):
                return True
            # ...
```

The `any(...)` will terminate when the first `True` is found, and return `True`.  If no `True` value is found, it will return `False`.

There is a similar function `all(...)`, which will terminate at the first `False` returning `False`.  If no `False` value is found, it returns `True`.